# "Deploy artifact to Maven Repositry" option is missing in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

we have an Apache Archiva running, and Jenkins CI. We need to deploy a simple maven jar, after the build is done, but the option labeled as "Deploy artifacts to Maven repository", is not being shown eligible as a Post Build Action (I took the image from another question):

[image: The action]
What do I have to do? Is it due to some bug or something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect you are using a `freestyle job` instead of a `maven job`. If not, please provide more details on what you have in the Build section.

Comment: @mdabdullah thanks for your comment!. We are using "top-level Maven tasks/targets" (I think it´s the correct translation, it is in Spanish) where we execute "clean install" and that sort of commands that belongs to Maven. I do not know if this helps you find out the problem.

Comment: Thanks from India, my Spanish friend, it does look like you are using a Freestyle job with Maven commands. Instead, can you use a Maven job itself? Instructions here
https://medium.com/@anusha.sharma3010/build-a-simple-maven-project-in-jenkins-da7a2a4ae202